# how to solve the keystone error whenever trying to install new package in ubuntu its getting error like subprocess error

Tags: ubuntu, keystone

how to solve the keystone error whenever trying to install new package in ubuntu its getting error like

> subprocess error
>   Reading package lists... Done
>   Building dependency tree
>   Reading state information... Done
>   nmap is already the newest version (7.01-2ubuntu2).
>   0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 256 not upgraded.
>   1 not fully installed or removed.
>   After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
>   Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
>   Setting up keystone (2:9.3.0-0ubuntu3.2) ...
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/usr/bin/keystone-manage", line 6, in 
>       from keystone.cmd.manage import main
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keystone/cmd/manage.py", line 32, in   
>       from keystone.cmd import cli
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keystone/cmd/cli.py", line 35, in   
>       from keystone.federation import idp
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keystone/federation/idp.py", line   23, in 
>       from saml2 import client_base
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/saml2/client_base.py", line 13, in   
>       from saml2.entity import Entity
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/saml2/entity.py", line 9, in   
>       from saml2.metadata import ENDPOINTS
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/saml2/metadata.py", line 3, in   
>       from saml2.sigver import security_context
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/saml2/sigver.py", line 8, in   
>       from OpenSSL import crypto
>   ImportError: No module named OpenSSL
>   dpkg: error processing package keystone (--configure):
>    subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
>   Errors were encountered while processing:
>    keystone
>   E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e6L6e.png)

Answer (score 0):

install upgrade the pip and also upgrade the setuptools
then after install the pyopenssl packege

```
   sudo pip install --upgrade pip
   sudo pip install --upgrade setuptools 
   sudo pip install pyopenssl
```